# QT creator and Qt ( just itself) difference - Starting QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, qt5

I'm asking for a good re-confirmation! (don't take it otherwise).. As I'm quite new in the Qt platform, I've found it quite confusing!! In Windows platform, you've: Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL) which is a whooping 644 MB file! & also the info about "Qt Creator" in download says:

> Blockquote Qt Creator 3.3.1 is included in the Qt 5.4.1 binary packages. If you need a standalone installer, please select the file according to your operating system from the list below to get the latest Qt Creator for your computer

--- this a layman would understand as Qt Creator is the GUI of Qt IDE 
& 
also you need to download "Qt 5.4.1 for Windows" which is a whooping 644MB !! 
so, WAIT FOR A MOMENT...

> Blockquote is this the case? or I've to download just the Qt Creator for my work?

Comment: You need the full package, Qt creator is just the ide, there are very few cases in which you need to download only creator, the only one I can think of now is that you already have Qt and you want to upgrade the Ide.

Comment: A whopping 644MB? The last Visual Studio edition I downloaded was 4.7GB to put that in perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Marco's comment explains it all. I don't know why you're bothered with the size of the package. What i want to add is, you can download Qt alone if you'd like to use a different IDE eg. CodeBlocks and set it up for Qt development but it's advisable to use Qt creator with Qt. Qt creator can't build and debug any code (except perhaps, you want to use it for other reasons) without Qt because Qt contains the necessary tools for that purpose.

So download Qt Creator alone if you already have Qt or want to update your old Qt creator and download Qt 5.4.1 for Windows if you want to do development on windows and already have Qt creator installed or any other IDE that can be setup for Qt development.